# What is the pin mapping when we use an ADC in micro STM32F401?

Tags: adc, stm32

If we wanted to capture continuous data and map it to a digital value we must use ADCs.

But there is a problem. If we set multiple pins as analog inputs, what are the channels corresponding to each pin in analog mode?

In the control registers, we don't have any pin that determines to capture on which pin and on which channel on ADC.

I read the reference manual but it says just configure some pin on a port in analog mode. But if we have multiple analog inputs and want to use multiple ADC channels, there are some difficulties with this and the mapping among analog input pins and ADC channels.

Comment: Please provide a link to the "reference manual" and tell us which sections you are reading.

Comment: No need for that because reference manual is useless in this regard. The information is in the datasheet.

Comment: @Justme Sorry, you are mistaken. ST datasheets only provide electrical characteristics and pinouts of the specific chips. The reference manuals provide actual programming details for the entire series. The OP seems to be more confused about using multiple channels than simple pin mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full datasheet for the entire STM32F40x family [here](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/dotNET/DM00031020RM.pdf). There are ways to configure ADC to automatically sweep across pins configured as ADC inputs and read the input on them. You can also manually do multiple single conversions, so check ADC1 reconfigure ADC for a different channel, check ADC2,... Read more in the supplied datasheet or learn how to use tools such as CUBE MX, which can do the configuration for you. You can also use already existing HAL libraries instead of writing your own functions to read ADC in various different modes. Combination of HAL and CUBE MX is what I would advise as you will only benefit from knowing how to work with those and they will make your life much simpler.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got -1. It lacks details, sure, but from the look at the original question nothing less than several pages with code samples will be of any help. And even then using Cube + HAL will get OP further and faster than explaining how registers work

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents to Daniel's answer. I would recommend reading the following application note

[AN3116](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00258017.pdf) "STM32 ADC modes and their applications"

for the explanation how multichannel ADC conversion works. Specifically, section 1.4 "Multichannel (scan) continuous conversion mode" would be of most interest to you. When you understand that, read

[AN4031](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00046011.pdf) "Using the STM32F2, STM32F4 and STM32F7 Series DMA controller"

because DMA in circular mode is the easiest way to get scan results into your application without wasting any CPU cycles.

The rest is simple - you specify which channels you want to sample and in which order, then tell DMA to transfer results into your own array of 16-bit integers. The converted voltage on corresponding pins will then "magically" appear in your array.